# Pass information from item to a item display page in PHP

Tags: php

OK so I'm doing a web application to sell games. 
I've done a cycle to put all the games from the database in the index page.
Now when a user clicks a game it goes to the page with the game's info.
How can I save the info from the database in session variables to use in the other page ?

btw: JOGO = GAME

```
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM JOGO');
          foreach ($stmt as $row){
            $_SESSION['id_jogo'] = $idJ;  
            echo '<link href="home/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.php" rel="stylesheet">';
            echo '<link href="style.php" rel="stylesheet">';
            echo  '


                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4" >   
                    <div class="card h-100 ">  
                      <a href="itempage.php"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">
                          <a href="#">  ' .$row["nome"].'   </a>
                        </h4>
                        <h5>' .$row["preco"].'€ </h5>
                        <p class="card-text">' .$row["descricao"].' </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Vendedor: </small>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div> ' ;



             }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing game id in session is not an option. Line

```
$_SESSION['id_jogo'] = $idJ;
```

(though I don't know where `$idJ` comes from), I presume that you want to put game id in session, something like

```
$_SESSION['id_jogo'] = $row['id']; // assuming id is a primary key.
```

But this will not work, as this line just overwrites `$_SESSION['id_jogo']` on every iteration.

Use standard approach with $_GET parameters, when your page url is `itempage.php?game_id=42`

In `itempage.php` you can get game id as `$_GET['game_id']` and use it in a query.

So, your markup is something like:

```
<a href="itempage.php?game_id=<?=$row['id']?>"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re initializing a session somewhere else in your code with `session_start()` you can create a new session variable name with `$_SESSION[‘some_key’] = ‘data’;`